# why "Error : IActiveDesktop undeclared indentifier" occurs even after incluing the specifed file?

Tags: com, visual-c++

I am  using IActiveDesktop interface to change wallpaper .
I have included files "shlobj.h" , "shlguid.h" for that in my MFC project.

But still i am getting error : "undeclared identifier IActiveDesktop" .
Can anybody tell me how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few more includes you'll have to add manually. See [ActiveDesktop Compilation Errors Under Visual C++ 6.0 MFC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196342) KB article.